# undefined method select_list using ruby with watir 2.0 & selenium web driver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm new to using ruby and watir and learning it as i go.

I'm trying to select an entry in a selection box using the select_list method but keep getting

```
'undefined method 'select_list' for #selenium::webdriver. <NoMethodError>
```

the line of code I'm using to make the selection is

```
browser.select_list(:name, "linkType").set("Content Page")
```

and I've also tried

```
browser.select_list(:name, "linkType").select("Content Page")
```

The site code i'm looking to call from is

```
<select name="linkType" size="4">
<option value="Content Page">Content Page</option>
<option value="Preset Page">Preset Page</option>
<option value="Form">Form</option>
</select>
```

I'm probably missing something simple, but this is my first time working with **ruby/watir/selenium**.So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be problem with browser, Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons for the exception.

**Browser is the wrong type**

Based on the exception, it is saying that `browser` is a Selenium::Webdriver object. To use the `select_list` method you need a Watir::Browser (or Watir::Element) object.

I am guessing that somewhere you have the line:

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

This is creating a Selenium browser/driver instead of a Watir browser. You want to do:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

**Using incorrect version of Watir**

Based on the title of the question, you are trying to use Watir 2.0 and Selenium-Webdriver. These are not compatible with each other. Watir 2.0, which is now Watir-Classic, does not use Selenium-Webdriver at all.

If you want to use Selenium-Webdriver with a Watir API (ie methods like `select_list`), you need to use the [Watir-Webdriver gem](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver).

In other words, the top of your script would have:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

Or, if you have the [Watir meta gem](https://github.com/watir/watir) installed, using any browser other than IE would cause the Watir-Webdriver gem to load:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

Comment: thanks, funnily enough, i was looking around for more help and started using require 'watir-webdriver' and got it working, but thanks for the help. Now trying to create classes variables so moving forward, but only slowly